# Какой язык программирования труднее всего декомпилировать?

Tags: декомпиляция

Есть небольшой скрипт на cmd. Необходимо его как можно лучше скрыть его от посторонних глаз. Если перенести его на java, то как я понимаю очень просто потом будет заинтересованным лицам используя JAD, получить исходный код. Я бы написал хотя бы часть кода на каком либо другом языке, если его сложнее декомпилировать. Понятно, что декомпилировать можно все что угодно, но думаю все таки можно найти менее распространенный язык, под который сложнее найти декомпилятор. Что посоветуете использовать?

Comment: Любой язык можно использовать и шифровать код, например через ionCube. Или же вообще защищать свой код с помощью авторских прав и т.д. Зависит от того, что это за код и почему так страшно, что его расшифуют

Comment: DexProtector также подойдёт

Comment: Спасибо. Для java видел обфускаторы, в них за месяц не разберешься. Информации мало на русском. Простое решение для java https://protector4j.com, но он платный. Не страшно что расшифруют, но это мои наработки. Подобный вопрос не раз всплывет в работе.

Comment: Попробуйте [APL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: 1956 года язык. Самое то)

Comment: Надо смотреть не на древность.

Comment: Про APL это я не всерьез. Вообще у меня bat файл. Там создание, удаление, переименование файлов, не более.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему лучший вариант это ассемблер или какой-то уже архаичный консольный язык (паскаль).

Comment: Пояснить можете почему паскаль? Чтоб понять на что смотреть при выборе.

Comment: Как я понимаю, паскаль, фортран и т.п. яп компилируют сразу в двоичный код, там нет промежуточного уровня как, например, IL в .NET у C#, нет метаданных в самой сборке. Это лишь мнение.

Comment: хорошо.          спасибо

Comment: Учтите, что разкомпилировать их, конечно, невозможно, но можно дизассемблировать. И не используйте версии языков, адаптированные под платформы, такие как .NET, они все сначала переводятся в IL-код, своего рода ассемблер.

Comment: Хорошо. Это я понял уже.

Comment: Так понимаю с++ тоже как паскаль.

Comment: "Как" паскаль скорее С. Если будете писать в Visual Studio на них, то создавайте неуправляемый код. По ним лучше спросить у специалистов сишников.